# PHPSpec - checking that a method has been called with a class instance argument

Tags: php, rspec, phpspec

I have the following test in RSpec:

```
it { is_expected.to respond_to(:dock).with(1).argument }
```

I need to replicate this test but using PHPSpec. My code is below:

```
function it_should_dock_a_bike()
{
    $bike = new \Bike();
    $this->dock($bike)->shouldReturnAnInstanceOf('Bike');
}
```

This code works, and it does fail when I exclude the $bike argument, but is there a better way to explicitly write the test similar to the example in RSpec?

Comment: Don't know RSpec, what `with(1).argument` means? Any argument?

Comment: I’d say only improvement would be:

    function it_should_dock_a_bike()
     {
        $bike = new \Bike();
        $this->dock($bike)->shouldReturnAnInstanceOf(Bike::class);
     }

Comment: @DonCallisto yes, any argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->dock(Argument::any())->shouldReturnAnInstanceOf(Bike::class);
```

is what you're looking for